# Can i use hibernate string entityGraph with subgraphs useing org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, entitygraph

I need to specify the fetching behavior of the relation entity of the root entity I want to use spring data org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph  annotation for that end specify graph right in repository above method.
but when I write

```
 @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {“order(items(subitems))”}) List findOrder()
```

i am getting error that
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [order(items(subitems))] on this ManagedType

Question: can I use somehow “order(items(subitems))” graph notation without using graph java API.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the following work for you?

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "order.items.subitems")
List findOrder()
```